# jquery run function in variable

Tags: jquery, eval

```
var x = '(( jQuery("*[data-customize-setting-link=rst_general_wrapper]:checked").val() == "2" ))';
        if( x ){
            alert(1);
        }else{
            alert(2);
        }
```

x must be a string.
I want to run this jquery in a variable without using the "eval". Not use Eval

Answer (score 0):

Hay Dear please try this one :)

```
var x = '(( jQuery("*[data-customize-setting-link=rst_general_wrapper]:checked").val() == "2" ))';
$("body > *:last-child").after('<script>var x = ' + x + '</script>');
if( x ){
    alert(1);
}else{
    alert(2);
}
```